# How to define rollback or rescue in ansible folder structure?

Tags: ansible

I would like to define rescue or rollback executions within my Ansible structure. I am using this recommended structure:

```
roles
  rolename
    files
    tasks
    templates
    handlers
    ...
```

I know that I can set blocks and within them a rescue section. But this seems a little clumsy to me and I would like to define all the rollback/rescue options within its own folder like

```
roles
  rolename
    ...
    tasks
    rollback/rescue
    handlers
    ...
```

This would make much more sense to me. I am speaking here about rollback, because I would like to be able to rollback a setup that I have created once with this role. I understand that the concept of rescue is a little bit different because it aims to fire when there is an error approached in executing a role. But I am hoping that I could use the concepts together while defining an anti-step to each step that I have defined in the role. And these anti-steps should have their own place and not included in the tasks files.

Comment: What prevents you from "defining an anti-step to each step" in *rollback* and including them whenever you want?

Comment: Maybe an unpopular opinion, but your rollback should be to a previous state. This means versioning your roles and applying the desired version of the role to the target system, not implementing "anti-tasks" in the role.

Answer (score 1):

For example, enable *backup* and *register* the results. As a last task create a record in the *journal* (see the declaration of the variables in the details under the line) and keep it in the cache

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_rollback/tasks/config.yml 
- name: config_01
  template:
    src: test.ini.j2
    dest: /tmp/test.ini
    backup: true
  register: config_01

- name: Write journal
  set_fact:
    journal: "{{ journal|d({})|combine({timestamp: journal_config_dict}) }}"
    cacheable: true
  vars:
    timestamp: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S'|strftime }}"
```

If you want to rollback the changes set the *rollback_journal_record*

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_rollback/rollback/config.yml 
- copy:
    remote_src: true
    src: "{{ item.value.backup_file }}"
    dest: "{{ item.value.dest }}"
  loop: "{{ journal[rollback_journal_record]|dict2items|selectattr('value.changed') }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

Let's test it. Given the file on the remote host

```ini
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/test.ini
test = X
```

Run the playbook

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
TASK [test_rollback : config_01] *************************************************************
changed: [test_11]

TASK [test_rollback : Write journal] *********************************************************
ok: [test_11]
  ...
```

The file changed

```ini
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/test.ini
test = A
```

and the record was added to the journal

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/ansible_cache.json/ansible_facts_test_11 
{
    "journal": {
        "2023-03-08_02_33_48": {
            "config_01": {
                "backup_file": "/tmp/test.ini.50045.2023-03-08@01:33:48~",
                "changed": true,
                "checksum": "6676ed8ea4caa804d3c5f0247c03ece8b7a80b0b",
                "dest": "/tmp/test.ini",
                "diff": [],
                "failed": false,
                "gid": 0,
                "group": "wheel",
                "md5sum": "0740a0962b43fa7bedf3dcd97e96697f",
                "mode": "0644",
                "owner": "root",
                "size": 9,
                "src": "/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678239225.046748-1753646-178984183659153/source",
                "state": "file",
                "uid": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the records in the journal

```yaml
shell>ansible-playbook pb.yml -t info -e debug_journal_records=true
  ...
TASK [test_rollback : debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    Journal records:
    - 2023-03-08_02_33_48
  ...
```

See the changed file(s) in the record

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -t info -e debug_journal_record=2023-03-08_02_33_48
  ...
TASK [test_rollback : debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    Journal changes of 2023-03-08_02_33_48:
    config_01:
        backup_file: /tmp/test.ini.50045.2023-03-08@01:33:48~
        changed: true
        checksum: 6676ed8ea4caa804d3c5f0247c03ece8b7a80b0b
        dest: /tmp/test.ini
        diff: []
        failed: false
        gid: 0
        group: wheel
        md5sum: 0740a0962b43fa7bedf3dcd97e96697f
        mode: '0644'
        owner: root
        size: 9
        src: /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678239225.046748-1753646-178984183659153/source
        state: file
        uid: 0
  ...
```

Rollback the changed file(s)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -t rollback -e rollback_journal_record=2023-03-08_02_33_48
  ...
TASK [test_rollback : copy] ******************************************************************
changed: [test_11] => (item=config_01)
  ...
```

The file was restored from the backup

```yaml
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/test.ini
test = X
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── roles
    └── test_rollback
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main.yml
        ├── rollback
        │   ├── config.yml
        │   └── main.yml
        ├── tasks
        │   ├── config.yml
        │   ├── info.yml
        │   ├── main.yml
        │   └── rollback.yml
        └── templates
            └── test.ini.j2

6 directories, 11 files
```

Enable caching

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
ansible_managed = {file}
deprecation_warnings=true
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
# fact_caching
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible_cache.json
fact_caching_prefix = ansible_facts_
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts 
test_11
test_12
test_13
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: test_11

  roles:
    - test_rollback
```

The role

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_rollback/tasks/main.yml 
- import_tasks: info.yml
  tags: info

- import_tasks: rollback.yml
  when: rollback_journal_record is defined
  tags: rollback

- import_tasks: config.yml
  tags: config
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_rollback/tasks/info.yml 
- debug:
    msg: |
      Journal records:
      {{ journal.keys()|list|to_nice_yaml }}
  when: debug_journal_records|d(false)|bool

- debug:
    msg: |
      Journal changes of {{ debug_journal_record }}:
      {{ journal[debug_journal_record]|dict2items|
         selectattr('value.changed')|items2dict|to_nice_yaml }}
  when: debug_journal_record is defined
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_rollback/tasks/rollback.yml 
- import_tasks: rollback/main.yml
  
- meta: end_play
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_rollback/tasks/config.yml 
- name: config_01
  template:
    src: test.ini.j2
    dest: /tmp/test.ini
    backup: true
  register: config_01

- name: Write journal
  set_fact:
    journal: "{{ journal|d({})|combine({timestamp: journal_config_dict}) }}"
    cacheable: true
  vars:
    timestamp: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S'|strftime }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_rollback/rollback/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: |
      Rollback {{ rollback_journal_record }}:
      {{ journal[rollback_journal_record]|dict2items|
         selectattr('value.changed')|
         map(attribute='value.dest')|to_nice_yaml }}
  when: debug|d(false)|bool

- import_tasks: rollback/config.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_rollback/rollback/config.yml 
- copy:
    remote_src: true
    src: "{{ item.value.backup_file }}"
    dest: "{{ item.value.dest }}"
  loop: "{{ journal[rollback_journal_record]|dict2items|selectattr('value.changed') }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_rollback/defaults/main.yml 
# Journal
journal_config_varnames: "{{ q('varnames', '^config_*') }}"
journal_config_vars: "{{ q('vars', *q('varnames', '^config_*')) }}"
journal_config_dict: "{{ dict(journal_config_varnames|zip(journal_config_vars)) }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_rollback/templates/test.ini.j2 
test = A
```